# ajax раз через раз ошибка 500/504

Tags: ajax, post

Добрый день друзья/товарищи. Весь интернет перерыл, ответа на свой вопрос не нашел. Прошу помощи...
У меня ajax срабатывает раз через раз. Бывает и 10 обращений - моментальные, отличные, а бывает валится в 500/504 ошибку.
Сразу error.log

> 2017/03/11 20:50:57 [error] 2310#2310: *11925 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 78.106.237.241, server: x-linkpay.com, request: "POST /actions/site_edit_banner.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://5.187.5.231:8443/actions/site_edit_banner.php", host: "x-linkpay.com", referrer: "https://x-linkpay.com/cabinet/edit_banner/296"

Сам ajax:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    var id = '<?php echo $getid; ?>';
    var url = $('#url').val();
    var ti = $('#ti').val();
    var cost = $('#cost').val();
    var cat = $('#cat').val();
    var how = $('#how').val();
    var bn_width = $('#bn_width').val();
    var bn_height = $('#bn_height').val();
    var bn_zagl = $('#bn_zagl').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/actions/site_edit_banner.php',
      data: {
        'id': id,
        'url': url,
        'ti': ti,
        'cost': cost,
        'cat': cat,
        'how': how,
        'bn_width': bn_width,
        'bn_height': bn_height,
        'bn_zagl': bn_zagl
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function(result) {
        if (result == '0') {
          $().toastmessage('showErrorToast', "Не заполнены все необходимые поля");
        }
        if (result == '1') {
          $().toastmessage('showSuccessToast', "Успешно");
          $(location).attr('href', '/cabinet');
        }
        if (result == '2') {
          $().toastmessage('showErrorToast', "Вы не авторизованы");
        }
        if (result == '3') {
          $().toastmessage('showErrorToast', "Ошибка");
        }
        if (result == '4') {
          $().toastmessage('showErrorToast', "Неверный адрес сайта");
        }
        if (result == '5') {
          $().toastmessage('showErrorToast', "Этот сайт уже есть в системе");
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

php Обработчик:

```php
<?php
include('../inc/conf.php');
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 'On');
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 'Off');
session_set_cookie_params(604800000, "/", SITE, false, false);
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["uid"]) || $_SESSION["uid"] != 301){
echo "2";
exit;
}

if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['url']) && isset($_POST['ti']) && isset($_POST['cost']) && isset($_POST['cat']) && isset($_POST['how']) && isset($_POST['bn_width']) && isset($_POST['bn_height']) && isset($_POST['bn_zagl'])){
if(!empty($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['url']) && !empty($_POST['ti']) && !empty($_POST['cost']) && !empty($_POST['cat']) && !empty($_POST['how']) && !empty($_POST['bn_width']) && !empty($_POST['bn_height']) && !empty($_POST['bn_zagl'])){
$id = intval($_POST["id"]);
$uid = intval($_SESSION["uid"]);
$url = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect_db, $_POST["url"]);
$ns = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($connect_db, "SELECT id,url,thumb FROM t_site WHERE id='$id'"));
$url = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect_db, $_POST["url"]);
$lr = stripos($url , "http");
if ($lr === false) { echo '4'; exit; }
$purln = parse_url($url);
$eurln = $purln['host'];
$purle = parse_url($ns['url']);
$eurle = $purle['host'];
$ti = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect_db, $_POST["ti"]);
$cost = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect_db, $_POST["cost"]);
$cat = intval($_POST["cat"]);
$bn_width = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect_db, $_POST["bn_width"]);
$bn_height = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect_db, $_POST["bn_height"]);
$bn_zagl = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect_db, $_POST["bn_zagl"]);
$how = intval($_POST["how"]);
$dt = time();
$file = "../thumbs/$dt.jpg";
$scr = "$dt.jpg";
$surl = "http://mini.s-shot.ru/1024x768/800/jpeg/?$url";
$content = file_get_contents($surl);
file_put_contents($file, $content);
mysqli_query($connect_db, "UPDATE `t_site` SET `url` = '$url', `ti` = '$ti', `cat` = '$cat', `cost` = '$cost', `how` = '$how', `bn_width` = '$bn_width', `bn_height` = '$bn_height', `bn_zagl` = '$bn_zagl' WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
echo '1';
} else { echo '0'; }
} else { echo '3'; }
?>
```

До кучи .htacces

```html
<files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
Options All -Indexes
ServerSignature Off
<FilesMatch ".(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf|js|css|pdf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</FilesMatch>
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
</ifModule>
<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on         Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk    Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file      \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include mime      ^text\.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime      ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime      ^image\.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=43200"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(flv|swf|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
Header unset Cache-Control
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 43200 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</ifModule>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^m_admin/user\/(.*?)$ m_admin/user.php?login=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^m_admin/ad_single\/(.*?)$ m_admin/ad_single.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^m_admin/edit\/(.*?)$ m_admin/edit.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^m_admin/view\/(.*?)$ m_admin/view.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^m_admin/moderation\/(.*?)$ m_admin/moderation.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^m_admin/sitestat\/(.*?)$ m_admin/sitestat.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^m_admin/adstat\/(.*?)$ m_admin/adstat.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^site\/(.*?)$ site.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^goto\/(.*?)$ goto.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^fromto\/(.*?)$ fromto.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^cabinet/site\/(.*?)$ cabinet/site.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^cabinet/sitestat\/(.*?)$ cabinet/sitestat.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^cabinet/adstat\/(.*?)$ cabinet/adstat.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^cabinet/edit_string\/(.*?)$ cabinet/edit_string.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^cabinet/edit_link\/(.*?)$ cabinet/edit_link.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^cabinet/edit_banner\/(.*?)$ cabinet/edit_banner.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^m_admin/edit_string\/(.*?)$ m_admin/edit_string.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^m_admin/edit_link\/(.*?)$ m_admin/edit_link.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^m_admin/edit_banner\/(.*?)$ m_admin/edit_banner.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^cabinet/ticket\/(.*?)$ cabinet/ticket.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^m_admin/ticket\/(.*?)$ m_admin/ticket.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%1/$0 [L,R=301]
```

Я прошу... нет, МОЛЮ! О помощи, голову себе всю изломал уже.

Answer (score 0):

Проверь правильно ли у тебя передает id параметр в ajax запросе.

И сделай проверку в php скрипте на `$getid` может он вообще не существует? вдруг  `$_GET['id']` пуст?

Comment: Передавал бы не верно по 10 раз подряд я думаю не срабатывал бы успешно... Так что этот вариант я думаю не при чем.

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю php, но у меня в Java подобная проблема была.Я установил connection.timeout(0). То есть время для connection не ограничено. А у тебя оно ограничено и через раз истекает, о чем и сообщение об ошибке. Надеюсь мой ответ будет полезен :-)

Comment: Понять бы где установить эту переменную )

Comment: Посмотри тут http://www.php.su/set_time_limit

Comment: Нет, не помогло. Проблема актуальна :(